# cvs auto setenv and login without typing password again

Tags: linux, shell, cvs

Hi I'm trying to logon to cvs automatically every time I start the machine. This works well but I have to manually type `cvs login` in the shell:

```
setenv CVSROOT :pserver:$USER@vlsj-cccc:/vols/cvsroot
```

So I tried to add the password in my .cshrc file and having trouble when inserting my password to it.

```
cvs -d  :pserver:$USER:password@vlsj-cccc:/vols/cvsroot login
```

It works in a normal script file, but not work in a `.cshrc` file. How to deal with it properly?